# copy files from SharePoint to SFTP

Tags: sharepoint, copy, sftp

Is there a way to copy SharePoint document library files to SFTP? I tried opening windows Explorer (with the help of swich) for SFTP and also had library opened in explorer mode. I can drag hand full of documents and move a across. but I can't copy 50,000 items from the document library to sftp. I tried copy and paste and nothing happens. May be a powershell way? or any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I solved the problem with non-coding approach.

1. Mapped "\intranet.domain.com\siteCollection\DocumentLibrary" to S:
2. Used WinSCP to upload Y: to Remove ftp.

Thanks